# Validating Checkbox not working in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, checkbox

It worked in the previous rails version. I can't find a solution for this.

```
    #Model

    validate  :branches_cannot_be_empty

    def branches_cannot_be_empty
       errors.add(:branches, "can't be empty") if branches.blank?
    end

    #View HAML
   .field.checkbox
     = f.label(:branch, "Assign to Branch")
     -if @march.branch_ids.include? ( branch.id )
      =check_box_tag "branches[#{branch.id}]", 1, true
     -else
      =check_box_tag "branches[#{branch.id}]"
     = branch.name
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot validate a checkbox like this - in a rails form (as well as most other frameworks, eg .net web forms) always send a value back for a checkbox.

When you render a checkbox, a hidden field is also rendered with the value of false. So if the checkbox is checked, you get a value of true but if a checkbox is not checked, you get the value of false not blank.

Read the gotcha section of the rails documentation here --> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box